# Replace '%@' with '%n$s' using groovy regex

Tags: android, regex, groovy

I have a string like `some text %@ some text %@ some text`
where `%@` is a obj-c formatting. I need to transform this string to `some text %1$s some text %2$s some text` , which is a android resource with formatting.

How can I do it using groovy regex?

Comment: you can do `splits` using `stringTokenizer` and later `replace`

Comment: @Aspicas could you add code snippet as answer?

Comment: of course let me write it please, wait a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
def s = 'some text %@ some text %@ some text'

def newS = 1.with { idx -> s.replaceAll(/%@/, { v -> "%${idx++}\$s" }) }
```

Which gives the output:

```
'some text %1$s some text %2$s some text'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an string `some text %@ some text %@ some text`.

You can divide that string using stringtokenizer:

***For example:***

```
String myString= "Hello world"

//we can divide my string using space as reference on this way.
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(myString, " ");
                        //here hello
                        String SplitFirst = tokens.nextToken();
                        //here world
                        String SplitSecond = tokens.nextToken();
```

***Second Example:***

```
String myString= "Hello:world:everybody"

//we can divide my string using `:` as reference on this way.
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(myString, ":");
                        //here hello
                        String SplitFirst = tokens.nextToken();
                        //here world
                        String SplitSecond = tokens.nextToken();
                        //here everybody
                        String SplitThird = tokens.nextToken();
```

Then on your question, you can do same process to do that but using as reference `%@`

When you have diferents strings you can use `replace` to change `%@`:

***For example***

```
String newString = string.replace("%@", "%1$s");
```

And later you can concatenate on new string:

Again, ***For example***

```
String NewConcatenateString= SplitFirst + SplitSecond + SplitThird......
```